# How to fill a Stack with 0xAA?

Tags: c, stack

I am trying to fill a stack (reserved by malloc) with the value 0xAA or 0b10101010. I think I manage to fill the stack, but printing it, I get different outputs (e83e83e83... or 41f41f41f... for example) depending on my stacksize.
Does anyone have an idea how to solve the problem?

```
int main(void) {
    int status;
    int stacksize = 1000;
    void* stack=malloc(stacksize);
    void* stackTop = stack + stacksize;
    for(int i =0; i<stacksize;i++){
        stackTop = "10101010";
        stackTop --;
    }
    stackTop =stack + stacksize;
    for(int i =0; i<stacksize;i++){
            printf("%x", stacksize);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: At the end, you print `stacksize` lots of times rather than the contents of the stack. Unfortunately there's problems on nearly every line of your code. Does your compile not produce warnings when you compile?

Comment: `memset(stack, 0xAA, stacksize)` fills memory with a given byte value.

Comment: `stackTop = "10101010";` is utterly wrong.  You are setting a void pointer to a string address, then not actually doing anything meaningful except leaking memory. Learn about the `*` and `&` operators, then use a pointer that represent the data you are going to write to the stack.

Comment: Your code is very broken. stackTop is initialized with a pointer BEHIND the stack. Then you assign the address of a static string to it. And then you decrease this address. Almost every line is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It's somewhat hard to understand from your code and comments, what you're actually trying to do. But if I were to extrapolate on it, you're trying to create a "stack", with an element size of a byte. Here's a quick-and-dirty implementation of such a stack, with bounds checking:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 1000

struct stack {
    int top;
    unsigned char elts[STACK_SIZE];
};

static void stack_push(struct stack *s, unsigned char elt) {
    if (s->top < STACK_SIZE-1) {
        s->elts[s->top++] = elt;
    } else {
        // No space left in the stack.
    }
}

static void stack_pop(struct stack *s) {
    if (s->top) {
        s->top--;
    } else {
        // Stack is empty
    }
}

static void stack_fill(struct stack *s, unsigned char v) {
    memset(s->elts, v, STACK_SIZE);
    s->top = STACK_SIZE-1;
}

int main(void) {
    // Example driver
    struct stack s;
    stack_fill(&s, 0xAA);

    for (int i = 0; i < STACK_SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%d: %02x\n", s.elts[s.top]);
        stack_pop(&s);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

As an improvement, you could consider e.g. having stack_pop return the popped element, or return some kind of an error if the stack is empty. Or a peek function which returns the top, or an error similar to the one earlier described. However, I omitted them for brevity.

EDIT: To initialize the stack, the only thing required is to set the top member to 0. Initialization function (if needed) is thus trivial to write.

Answer (score -1):

You are filling the stack with strings of chars and reading pointers to them.

The answer given by Paul Hankin in the comment states one of the correct solutions that is using

```
memset(stack, 0xAA, stacksize);
```

to fill your stack

thus producing the following code

```
int main()
{
    int status;
    int stacksize = 1000;
    void* stack = malloc(stacksize);
    void* stackTop = stack + stacksize;
    memset(stack, 0xAA, stacksize); 
    for(int i =0; i < stacksize;i++){
        printf("%x\n", ((unsigned char*)stack)[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code is still broken and you copied the errors. Example: `stack + stacksize` is beyond the stack.

Comment: `((int*)stack)[i]` reads out of bounds of the allocated memory (assuming sizeof(int)>1).

Comment: @reichhart I just decided to leave the stackTop value in, as it is not used anywhere, does literally nothing and is removed in the compilation process ¯\_(ツ)_/¯